# How to use join query to fetch data from more than two tables without foreign key and primary key

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

Once I need your help,

I have three table in my database.

1> **wedding**

```
Column Name    Data Type
-------------------------------------
wedID          Int (primary key)
wedName        varchar (50)
```

2> **selectSite**

```
Column Name   Data Type
-----------------------------------
wedID         Int (without foreign key and primary key with null allow)
siteID        Int (without foreign key and primary key with null allow)
siteStatus    varchar(50)
```

3> **webSite**

```
Column Name   Data Type
--------------------------------      
siteID        Int (Primary Key) 
siteName      varchar(50)
siteFile      varchar(MAX)
```

I want the following output:

```
 ws.siteID     ws.siteName     ws.siteFile    s.wedID   s.sitestatus
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1              Show           show.jpeg      6         Yes
 2              My View        my view.png    5     
 3              Dream          dream.jpeg     3
```

`ws` is alias of `webSite` table, `s` is alias of `siteSelect` table.

All data from `webSite` table and only data from `siteSelect` where `s.siteStatus` do not display `Yes` if wedID not match

I try following sql query

```
select 
    DISTINCT(ws.siteID), s.wedID, ws.siteName, 
    ws.siteFile, s.siteStatus 
from wedding wd, webSite ws 
left outer join siteSelect s on ws.siteID = s.siteID 
where wd.wedID = @wedID
```

but output is like this:

```
 ws.siteID     ws.siteName     ws.siteFile    s.wedID   s.sitestatus
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
 1              Show           show.jpeg      6         Yes
 2              My View        my view.png    5         Yes
 3              Dream          dream.jpeg     3         Yes
```

Answer (score 2):

**[DEMO SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/78fe1/1)**

Check the demo add some  values as you having and run this query

```
select 
   ws.siteId, ws.siteName, ws.siteFile, ss.wedID,
   (case 
      when ss.wedID = 1 then ss.siteStatus else '' end) as siteStatus
from 
   website ws 
join 
   selectsite ss on ss.siteID=ws.siteID
```

let me knw if any prob

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select 
    DISTINCT(ws.siteID), s.wedID, ws.siteName, ws.siteFile, 
    (case 
        when s.wedID = @wedID 
        then s.siteStatus 
        else '' end) as siteStatus, wd.wedName
from webSite ws  
left join selectSite s on ws.siteID = s.siteID  
Left Join wedding wd on wd.wedID = s.wedID
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function. It's a set quantifier (you can either use `SELECT ALL` or `SELECT DISTINCT`) and is applied to the whole row in this case (duplicate rows removed from the result set).